# Error on get doctrine from SonataAdmin

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I have a problem on create configureFormFields() for SonataAdmin. 
I will try use getDoctrine from entity and extended from base Controller(in my Bundle). 
But, symfony return error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php
>   on line 191

How to solve this.

Comment: Probably duplicate of [this][1]
Search answers before you submit a question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281713/fatalerrorexception-error-call-to-a-member-function-has-on-a-non-object