# FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a read a lot of topics on this and I can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

I feel like the problem is obvious and maybe I have just been staring at it too long.

The error is FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function has() on a non-object in /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 198

Looking at the error line, it says.

```
public function getDoctrine()
    {
        if (!$this->container->has('doctrine')) {
            throw new \LogicException('The DoctrineBundle is not registered in your application.');
        }

        return $this->container->get('doctrine');
    }
```

Here is my code...

This is the main controller that is calling the DAO Controller

```
public function clickThroughAction(request $request, $hash)
    {
        if (isset($hash)) {
            $dbController = $this->get('database_controller');
            print_r($dbController->getReferralIdByHash($hash));
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
        } else {
            return 0;

        }
    }
```

This is the service that is being used.

```
services:
    database_controller:
        class:  Fuel\FormBundle\Controller\DatabaseController
```

This is the dao controller that is calling the database.

```
public function getReferralIdByHash($hash)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'Select u From FuelFormBundle:UserReferrals u WHERE u.user_hash = :hash'
        )->setParameter('hash', $hash);

        $referral = $query->getResult();

        if (!$referral) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product referral found'
            );
            $logger = $this->get('logger');
            $logger->info('I just got the logger');
            $logger->crit('An error occurred, hash for referrals is not recognized. current hash is: ' . $hash . " .");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
        }

        $clickThroughCount = $referral[0]->getClickThrough();
        $referral[0]->setClickThrough($clickThroughCount + 1);
        $em->flush();
        return $referral;
    }
```

I think the problem is that the doctrine container is not present which is why I am having issues.  I am not sure how to solve this.

Any help is appreciated.   Thanks!

Edit

---

Ok so here is what I changed.

Main Controller stayed the same.

DAO Controller a couple of things were added.

```
class DatabaseController extends Controller{
    protected  $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager) {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }
public function getReferralIdByHash($hash)
    {
        $em = $this->entityManager;
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'Select u From FuelFormBundle:UserReferrals u WHERE u.user_hash = :hash'
        )->setParameter('hash', $hash);

        $referral = $query->getResult();

        if (!$referral) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No product referral found'
            );
            $logger = $this->get('logger');
            $logger->info('I just got the logger');
            $logger->crit('An error occurred, hash for referrals is not recognized. current hash is: ' . $hash . " .");
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
        }

        $clickThroughCount = $referral[0]->getClickThrough();
        $referral[0]->setClickThrough($clickThroughCount + 1);
        $em->flush();
        return $referral;
    }
}
```

Service ended up looking like this

```
services:
     database_controller:
          class:  Fuel\FormBundle\Controller\DatabaseController
          arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Comment: What's `var_dump($this->container)` show? The error message basically proves it won't be an object, so see what it really is at that point.

Comment: Where is `$this->container` set? It seems like the problem is most likely there.

Comment: I guess thats what I am missing, however I still don't understand what I am missing.  I have read the documentation but there is disconnect, and I'm missing something.

Comment: I guess in general I am having a hard time grasping Dependency Injection.  I have read through Symfonys documentation and when I finish I just shake my head.

Comment: I suggest you read [Dependency Injection Demystified](http://www.jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html). FWIW it seems like maybe you have Doctrine misconfigured or something. To figure out how, it looks like you will have to figure our where and how (whether in application logic or Symfony's core) `$this->container` gets set.

Comment: I appreciate the link however that is pretty basic and really isn't all that complex.  Where I am stuck is with a large project.  It seems to get other items in separate files to work I am missing something.  I am not sure why Doctrine wouldn't work in one controller but works in another.  If I combine those controllers everything works without issue.  As soon as I separate them I get this error.  Do I need to hand the controller that is doing the calling to the DAO Controller to call Doctrine?  I feel as thought the problem is not that complex I feel like I am just missing something small!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The problem is the container not being injected into the controller here.

Normally, Symfony does this automatically if you're extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller`, which itself extends `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware`:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class YourController extends Controller
```

The container is injected into the controller (if not explicitly defined as a service) using [setter injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html#setter-injection) calling the method `setContainer()` with the container as an argument.

Now, as you configured your controller as a service you need to add the setContainer call to your service configuration:

```
services:
    database_controller:
        class:  Fuel\FormBundle\Controller\DatabaseController
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Clear your cache afterwards.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  However I do have a question.  If one controller is calling a method from another controller and both extend controller shouldn't the container already be set on both?  Or is it that anything being called is not set automatically?

Comment: i guess your other controller is not defined as a service - that's why injection happens automagically in the other controller but not for the one defined as a service (if missing the setter call in the service definition). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes!  Huge help!  Thank you sir, this clears up a lot of confusion for me.  I was about to swear off Symfony for good!  ha!

Comment: Just to be clear I would add this correct? `public function setContainer($container){
        $this->container = $container;
    }`

Comment: This method is provided by `ContainerAware` which `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` **already** extends. So as long as you're extending the default controller you won't need to add the method to your class manually. Otherwise you could add the method without extending `Controller` (if you can live without the aliases provided in there like `$this->getDoctrine()` instead of `$this->container->get('doctrine')` ) - Just have a look at [the **class**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php). Clear?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would make a controller a service. For what use case? Normally a service is a Plain Old PHP Object.

About your problem .. since you are using the controller as a service it does not get the container automatically. So you have to inject the entire container, which is kind of heavy if you just need doctrine.

So it's better just to inject the things you really need. To inject doctrine, in your yml below `class:`

```
arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
```

Then in your controller constructor:

```
public function __construct($entityManager) {
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}
```

Possible you will need to call the parent constructor (be aware of that).

If you want do inject the complete service container anyway, here is the right section in the manual how you can do that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/scopes.html#passing-the-container-as-a-dependency-of-your-service

Comment: So I would say.
'public $entityManager;`  Then give your constructor and then use `$entityManager` in the createQuery rather than `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();`

Comment: This is correct.  I will post the additional changes I made in my question.  Thanks for the help!  I would vote up but I am under 15 rep.  Sorry!

Comment: while injecting only the services you need is a good practice, my answer is more generic and solves the issue for all controllers defined as services. Other users might run into the issue and be trying to access multiple different services in their controllers using `$this->container->get('service_name')` :-)

Answer (score 1):

One more suggestion: when you are moving database connection out of main controller you need to construct new instance of Entity Manager for instance:

```
class StoreController extends Controller{
     public function addstoreAction(Request $request){
     $checkStore = new StoreExistsCheck($this ->getDoctrine()->getManager());
     //your code here
     }
```

using /myBundle/Model folder

```
namespace myBundle\Model;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use myBundle\Entity\Store;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query;


class StoreExistsCheck extends Controller{

protected $em = null;
protected $kernel = null;

public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;

}
public function storeExists($argosStore){
    $storeExists = $this->em ->getRepository('myBundle:Store')
                       ->findOneBystoreNumber($argosStore->getStoreNumber());
     return $storeExists;

}
```