# Symfony 3 - FOSRestBundle - Inject Dependency into Service

Tags: symfony, fosrestbundle

This must be a simple oversight - why isn't my *entity_menus* parameter being injected into the StoreController?

This is the error I am seeing:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Controller\Api\Admin\Common\StoreController::__construct() must be of the type array, none given

The relevant parts of **services.yml**

```
parameters:
    entity_menus: [ 'manufacturers', 'vendors' ]

services:
    app.admin.store_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\Api\Admin\Common\StoreController
        arguments:
            - '%entity_menus%'
```

The **controller:**

```
class StoreController extends FOSRestController
{

    private $entityMenus;

    public function __construct( Array $entityMenus )
    {
        $this->entityMenus = $entityMenus;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated **services.yml** like so to set the service container:

```
app.admin.store_controller:
    class: AppBundle\Controller\Api\Admin\Common\StoreController
    arguments: ['%entity_menus%']
    calls:
        - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19283476/2182349

I updated **routing_rest.yml** to use the service name and the class:

```
app_admin_common_store_menu:
    type:     rest
    class: AppBundle\Controller\Api\Admin\Common\StoreController
    resource: app.admin.store_controller
    name_prefix:   app_admin_api_store_
    prefix: /api/store
```

Thanks to: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/issues/990